# Different kinds of endnote

Tags: footnotes, endnotes

I'm trying to make a document that has different kinds of *endnote* -- one Roman numerals, the other Arabic numerals. I found a solution to a similar request but with footnotes instead of endnotes using the manyfoot package. But I'm having trouble getting manyfoot to play nice with the endnotes package.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{manyfoot}
\usepackage{endnotes}


\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[roman]

\let\footnote=\endnote
\let\footnoteB=\endnote

\begin{document}

This is a sentence.\footnote{This kind of endnote I want to be the usual 
arabic numerals.} This is another sentence.\footnoteB{This kind of endnote I 
 want to be roman numerals.} But you'll see after `Notes' below everything is 
a Roman numeral.

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do exactly the same, and I came up with a solution. It's not the tidiest, as it involves two different packages for endnotes, but it does the work while causing no trouble that I know of.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{list-name={Enotez Name},reset=true,backref=true,list-heading=\section*{#1}}
 
\usepackage{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{Pagenote Name}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[2]{}
\renewcommand\thepagenote{\alph{pagenote}}
\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1} }
\renewcommand{\notenuminnotes}[1]{\textsuperscript{#1} }
         
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

This is a Pagenote.\pagenote{Note with Pagenote.} This is an Enotez.\endnote{End note with Enotez.} 
This is another Pagenote.\pagenote{Second Pagenote.} This is another Enotez.\endnote{Second Enotez.}

\printendnotes
\printnotes*
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just remember to place `\printendnotes` and `\printnotes*` (with the asterisk!) at the end of the chapter (or section, etc.)